# Entity Framework Select with Include + Group By Count + Paging and Projection

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dto, projection

I'm trying to do a query with EF6 that would eager load a related object then group it then count the total number of related records and do paging but so far i am not successful.

Here is my attempt but it only do a join and paging

```
                                             _dbcontext.PublicUsers
                                            .Include(x=> x.DocumentIndices)
                                            .OrderBy(x=> x.Lastname)
                                            .ThenBy(x=> x.Firstname)
                                            .Skip((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize)
                                            .Take(request.PageSize)
                                            .ToList()
                                            .Select(x => new PublicUserList
                                                {

                                                    Id = x.Id,
                                                    Email = x.Email,
                                                    Firstname = x.Firstname,
                                                    Lastname = x.Lastname,
                                                    Middlename = x.Middlename,
                                                    Fullname = x.Fullname,
                                                    NoOfResults = x.DocumentIndices.Count()
                                                }).ToList();
```

Is there any way to do the three operation (join + group by count + paging) in one single trip to db in EF6?

Comment: The answer is yes. But that's the only thing we can say with the information you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misreading this, I think it's simply a matter of removing a couple of lines:

```cs
_dbcontext.PublicUsers
    .OrderBy(x=> x.Lastname)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.Firstname)
    .Skip((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize)
    .Take(request.PageSize)
    .Select(x => new PublicUserList
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Email = x.Email,
        Firstname = x.Firstname,
        Lastname = x.Lastname,
        Middlename = x.Middlename,
        Fullname = x.Fullname,
        NoOfResults = x.DocumentIndices.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```